# Which Java XML parser to use?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-parsing

I found from this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/#) that there are several types of XML parsers in Java. Would you help me to choose which one will consume less memory and will work faster:

```
DOM XML Parser
SAX XML Parser
JDOM XML Parser
JAXB
```

I want to create Java server application with C client which communicate over network using XML. 
If I choose to use JAXB can I easy integrate it with `libxml`? What are the possible problems that might occur if I use JAXB and `libxml` to transfer data between the applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are more parsing techniques, not actual parsing tools.  Xerces is an example of a parsing tool.

SAX is good for speed, and parsing event processing.  Parsing from events can easily allows you to skip uninteresting events, and the penalties for skipping is low.  While the entire document is read, there is no need to store it, so SAX can process documents larger that the system memory.

DOM is good for holding the entire document in memory.  Doing so easily allows you to do work the requires all elements of the document (cross referencing, etc).  This convenience comes at a cost, unlike SAX, you must have sufficient memory to hold the whole document.

JDOM is basically DOM, but with a different programming interface.  It supposes that it's programming interface is more in-line with Java, whatever that means.

JAXP is a suite of XML handling tools which contains SAX and DOM interfaces in a pluggable manner which easily allows you to swap out the back end implementation.

JAXB is a suite of XML handling tools which provide convenience mapping of XML to regular Java objects, and generation of XML from regular Java objects.

Personally, I like SAX, but for efficient parsing with SAX, you should use a stack and context-sensitive parser chunks that are pushed onto the stack and popped off of it, yeilding the object that the XML mapped to.  The idea is that you maintain your position in the document as a StringBuffer, and then push in a handler to handle the entering element, which then processes all events until it detects the right exit event.  Then the above handler reads the object out of the popped sub-handler.  A technique like this requires a bit of work, but can bridge the speed of SAX with the convenience of DOM, yielding *your own* object tree (instead of a tree of "nodes").

Comment: +1 for use of the stack.

Comment: JAXP is a suite of XML handling tools, JAXB is for converting domain objects to/from XML.

Comment: Sorry, must have misread the P.  You're absolutely right, will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use less memory, I would go with SAX. It is an event-based parsing utility. The entire XML file will not be loaded into memory as like a DOM object. You save in memory the things you wish to save. Another good thing about SAX is that you only control the events you want, which can really increase the speed of the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

DOM will use more memory - you will nead to create whole xml DOM model in memory. So SAX or STAX will allow to parse what you need and save a memory.

JAXB allow you automatic mapping from beans to xml and reverse.